# Condition and max reference in redshift window function

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a list of dates, accounts, and sources of data. I'm taking the latest `max` date for each account and using that number in my window reference.

In my window reference, I'm using `row_number ()` to assign unique rows to each account and sources of data that we're receiving and sorting it by the `max` date for each account and source of data. The end result should list out one row for each unique account + source of data combination, with the max date available in that combination. The record with the highest date will have 1 listed.

I'm trying to set a condition on my window function where only rows that populate with 1 are listed in the query, while the other ones are not shown at all. This is what I have below and where I get stuck:

```
SELECT
  date,
  account,
  data source,
  MAX(date) max_date,
  ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY account ORDER BY max_date) ROWNUM
FROM table
GROUP BY
  date,
  account,
  data source
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I can elaborate on anything if necessary

Comment: Do you need the row number for anything besides uniqueness?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly this SQL would do the trick

```
SELECT 
  date,
  account,
  data source,
  MAX(date) max_date
FROM (    
      SELECT
        date,
        account,
        data source,
        MAX(date) max_date,
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY account ORDER BY max_date) ROWNUM
      FROM table
      GROUP BY
        date,
        account,
        data source
  )
where ROWNUM = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need the row number for anything other than uniqueness then a query like this should work:

```
select distinct t.account, data_source, date
from table t
join (select account, max(date) max_date from table group by account) m
on t.account=m.account and t.date=m.max_date
```

This can still generate two records for one account if two records for different data sources have the identical date. If that is a possibility then mdem7's approach is probably best.

It's a bit unclear from the question but if you want each combination of account and data_source with its max date making sure there are no duplicates, then distinct should be enough:

```
select distinct account, data_source, max(date) max_date
from table t
group by account, data_source
```